# Flutter create (OS Error: Access is denied. , errno = 5)

Tags: flutter

I am about create a new flutter project and suddenly flutter create command does not work.

This is the error even if I ran as administrator. (OS Error: Access is denied. , errno = 5)

I ran "flutter create UserApp" and this is the output

[image]

flutter doctor

[image: Flutter doctor]

Answer (score 1):

Run your command with administrator privileges. 
[image]

Search the Command prompt and click on Run as administrator.
Now run your command.

> Tip: Instead of creating a project in Desktop or OS Drive, try creating a project in any other drives. In that case, there are fewer chances of getting permission error.